# SagePay V3 PayPal Integration Issues. Anyway to track/view errors?

Tags: paypal, opayo

Not really a technical issue but we've upgraded Sagepay to V3 but PayPal integration won't work.  Returns an error of "PayPal returned an error, please try different card." to SagePay screen.

Contacted Sage who have said the issue is directly with PayPal.  Now awaiting a response back from PayPal.

This is only on our Live environment, Test Environment for PayPal works fine.

Is there anyway to view error logs from PayPal into what errors PayPal is generating?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Billing Agreement is set to 0 for SagePay V3 forms for PayPal.  Otherwise extra configuration within PayPal is required.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to view logs from the Sage Pay side (not sure about PayPal, but unlikely).

However, have you checked that the live Paypal account has granted API permissions to Sage Pay (paypal_api1.protx.com)?

Comment: The SagePay integration to PayPal was correct, found it was due to a new mandatory setting about billing agreements within PayPal.